# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s

Tags: xcode5

There are some static libraries ,application program which was created as to use these static libraries.When i build it i got following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:

"std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_out_of_range() const", referenced from:
  std::__1::vector<sRepProps*, std::__1::allocator<sRepProps*> >::at(unsigned long) in libMediaFramework.a(seg_mgr.o)
  std::__1::vector<sSegUrl*, std::__1::allocator<sSegUrl*> >::at(unsigned long) in libMediaFramework.a(list_url_map.o)
  std::__1::vector<sConfigData*, std::__1::allocator<sConfigData*> >::at(unsigned long) in libMediaFramework.a(seg_track.o)
"std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
  std::__1::vector<sRepProps*, std::__1::allocator<sRepProps*> >::insert(std::__1::__wrap_iter<sRepProps* const*>, sRepProps* const&) in libMediaFramework.a(CMPDParser.o)
  void std::__1::vector<sRepProps*, std::__1::allocator<sRepProps*> >::__push_back_slow_path<sRepProps* const>(sRepProps* const&) in libMediaFramework.a(CMPDParser.o)
  void std::__1::vector<sSegUrl*, std::__1::allocator<sSegUrl*> >::__push_back_slow_path<sSegUrl* const>(sSegUrl* const&) in libMediaFramework.a(CMPDParser.o)
  void std::__1::vector<sTrackInfo*, std::__1::allocator<sTrackInfo*> >::__push_back_slow_path<sTrackInfo* const>(sTrackInfo* const&) in libMediaFramework.a(CMPDParser.o)
  void std::__1::vector<sSegNwStats*, std::__1::allocator<sSegNwStats*> >::__push_back_slow_path<sSegNwStats* const>(sSegNwStats* const&) in libMediaFramework.a(seg_mgr.o)
  void std::__1::vector<DashSegTrack*, std::__1::allocator<DashSegTrack*> >::__push_back_slow_path<DashSegTrack* const>(DashSegTrack* const&) in libMediaFramework.a(seg_mgr.o)
  void std::__1::vector<sUrlMapItem*, std::__1::allocator<sUrlMapItem*> >::__push_back_slow_path<sUrlMapItem* const>(sUrlMapItem* const&) in libMediaFramework.a(list_url_map.o)
```

I am new to xcode .,does anyone have idea whats the issue??

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions :

1.When you add any static file make a best practice to add from build phases -> Add other .. any static library please dont try to copy paste it.

2.Check that architecture armv7 is selected and you can give it a boolean value to YES.